# TLS on already established connection

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'm writing Java XMPP server with akka io/streams. According to the XMPP spec the connection mode could be switched on the fly to TLS mode. Is there any good/standard way to do this using either akka.io, or akka.streams? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's possible with 2 stateful stages, one on inbound, one on outbound.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/yPtCVRXPW10) is the corresponding thread on google groups.

> Basically what I did was have a stateful stage on inbound and outbound[1] that I then mapped to something based on whether it needed to be secure or not. Then I used a broadcast/merge approach to send it to the TLS side and non-TLS side and just had each one ignore the message based on whether encryption was needed or not[0].

Hope this helps. Still struggling with basic TlsSsl Flow Connection to my TCP Socket myself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! You are correct, I have realized, that SslTls and streams in general are completely irrelevant, because of their synchronous nature: they are controlled by incoming messages which is not the case in protocols like IMAP/XMPP where server can start communication. So I have implemented my own TLS support over akka.io.Tcp. Before going this way I have found that you can have a proxy stateful actor which have business logic stream inside with or without SslTls middle layer in it. May be you can use this construction in your case.